# suitecrm ошибка на вкладке администрирование

Tags: unix

https://suitecrm.com/download

захожу в администрирование и получаю

> Strict Standards: Declaration of
>   DeployedRelationships::findRelatableModules() should be compatible
>   with
>   AbstractRelationships::findRelatableModules($includeActivitiesSubmodules
>   = true) in F:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\crm\modules\ModuleBuilder\parsers\relationships\DeployedRelationships.php
>   on line 48
>
> Strict Standards: Declaration of DeployedRelationships::build() should
>   be compatible with AbstractRelationships::build($basepath,
>   $installDefPrefix, $relationships) in
>   F:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\crm\modules\ModuleBuilder\parsers\relationships\DeployedRelationships.php
>   on line 48
>
> Strict Standards: Static function
>   AbstractMetaDataParser::_trimFieldDefs() should not be abstract in
>   F:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\crm\modules\ModuleBuilder\parsers\views\AbstractMetaDataParser.php
>   on line 122
>
> Strict Standards: Non-static method SubPanel::getModuleSubpanels()
>   should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible
>   context in
>   F:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\crm\modules\ModuleBuilder\Module\StudioModule.php
>   on line 306

нужно как-то конфиг по особому настроить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно дело в пермишенах на файлы.

Попробуйте в корне:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .
sudo chmod -R 755 .
sudo chmod -R 775 cache custom modules themes data upload config_override.php
```

Comment: а при условии что это openserver?

Comment: @des1roer тогда почитайте это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248952/php-5-disable-strict-standards-error и поправьте php.ini, может поможет